# Swift: how to initialize multiple data sources for multiple collection view in one view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have multiple collection views in scroll view. I have an issue with data being not displayed properly (number of items on the 1st page is the same as on the last one). I suppose the issue is in datasource objects for collection views. I read that:

collectionView.dataSource = MyDataSource()
is wrong as dataSource is a weak reference so it needs to be stored by some strong reference to be alive after creating it. Added a private property in a ViewController to keep the strong reference, initialising and then assigning it fixes the issue

But I don't understand how can I do it for multiple datasets?

```
  pages = musicItems.count/6+1 //numberOfItems%itemsOnTheScreen
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    self.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    bounds = self.scrollView.bounds

    let flowLayout = CVLayout()
    for i in 0...pages-1 {
        let x = bounds.width*CGFloat(i)
        let y = bounds.origin.y
        let width = bounds.width
        let height = bounds.height
        let collectionViewElement = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x:x,y:y,width:width,height:height), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        if let page = i as? Int {
            collectionViewElement.register(ImageCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell\(page)")}

        var ds: CVDataSource = CVDataSource()
        ds.page = i
        ds.itemsCount = itemsOnThePage(currentPage: i)
        collectionViewElement.delegate = ds//self
        collectionViewElement.dataSource = ds//self
        print("set value \(i)")

        collectionViewElement.isScrollEnabled = false
        collectionViewElement.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.scrollView.addSubview(collectionViewElement)

    }
```

Comment: Elena please upload any screen shot, for better understanding of your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Add an array to your view controller `var dataSources: CVDataSource = []` and then inside the loop above add the data sources `dataSources.append(ds)`.   Your VC will have a strong ref to the array which will have a strong refs to each data source.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused not by data source, but by the same layout object I used. This question can be considered as a duplicate of: [UICollectionView numberOfItemsInSection being called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586512/uicollectionview-numberofitemsinsection-being-called-twice) (found the answer there).